# Displaying a specific list based on dropdown selection in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm wanting to show a specific div based on the selection in a drop down and hide the other list.  and Vice versa.

This is what I've got but I can't seem to get it working.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged1">            
    <asp:ListItem Text="Fruits" Value="2014"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Colors" Value="2013"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<div id="div2014" runat="server">
    <ul>
        <li>Apples</li>
        <li>Oranges</li>
        <li>Bananas</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="div2013" runat="server">
    <ul>
        <li>Red</li>
        <li>White</li>
        <li>Blue</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My C# code is

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    div2014.Visible = false;
    div2013.Visible = false;

    switch (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text)
    {
        case "2014":
            div2014.Visible = true;
            break;
        case "2013":
            div2013.Visible = true;
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `AutoPostBack` attribute to your `DropDownList`:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged1" AutoPostBack="True">
```

Change your code behind to this:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    div2014.Visible = false;
    div2013.Visible = false;

    switch (DropDownList1.SelectedValue)
    {
        case "2014":
            div2014.Visible = true;
            break;
        case "2013":
            div2013.Visible = true;
            break;
    }
}
```

And you want to hide both div before selecting a value:

```
<div id="div2014" runat="server" Visible="false">
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks a ton.  Switching "DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text" to "DropDownList1.SelectedValue" was the solution along with the AutoPostBack.